# How to correct the skewed perspective of an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, transformation, projection

I'm trying to transform this image:

[image: img1]

into something like this:

[image: imgTransformed]

in MATLAB, basically by matching the corners of the blue square with the corners of the image and making every other pixel transform accordingly.

I can find the corners of the distorted blue square and its centroid, its border and diagonals, if any of these can be useful for the solution.

I thought that I could create a projective tform based on matching corners.
My attempt was:

```
img = imread('img1.png');

if size(img,3)==3
   img = rgb2gray(img);
end

movingPoints = [12 17; 253 16; 269 259;16 256]; %coordinate of distorted corners 
fixedPoints=[0 0;size(img,1) 0;size(img,1) size(img,2);0 size(img,2)]; %coordinate of image's corners 
TFORM = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'projective');
R=imref2d(size(img),[1 size(img,2)],[1 size(img,1)]);

imgTransformed=imwarp(imread('img1.png'),TFORM,'OutputView',R);
figure, imshow(imgTransformed);
```

But it seems to accomplish almost nothing. I also tried with:

- `TFORM = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'affine')`
- `TFORM = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'polynomial',2)` finding other 2 control points.

But still no result.

I know the OpenCV functions `getperspectivetransform` and `warpPerspective` can do something like this. Is there a way to do it in MATLAB?

Comment: "no result" means that you don't see what you expected? Can you add what is actually your result (load an image in you question)?

Comment: My approach is using OpenCV, however you can use the same in MATLAB as well. Binary threshold your image -> Find contour -> Fit rectangle around your contour -> Obtain edge info of the rectangle -> Detect line -> Get angle using `atan2` or something similar available in MATLAB.

Comment: "no result" means that the image is basically the same, with no major changes occured. It's just a cut version of (https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Axx.png) because of ('OutpuView',R).